# Issues after update 16.04 - 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade

Apologies in advance for the long introduction but I figured it would be better to give as much background as possible. I recently tried upgrading my HP Z420 workstation from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS. While updating, Ubuntu froze at the instance shown

[image: here]

I then rebooted after which I consistently got a kernel panic, as shown

[image: here]

I then booted from a live CD and ran `bootrepair`, with output shown [info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/88zv72rF7Q/)

This solved the Kernel Panic. However, now I only get a blank screen (same color as in Grub2).

When I enter Grub and select an earlier kernel, Ubuntu 18.04 loads but I only get a command line login, not a GUI. At the command I tried re-running `apt-get update` but this also gave errors relating to metadata, see

[image: here]

I am at a total loss how to get things up and running again, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**: according to janmyszkier's answer I checked the HDD for errors using the Disks utility (extended self-test) and, reassuringly, no issues were found.

**UPDATE2**: I tried using LiveCD and chroot method in a virtual console to try and redo the upgrade, but errors remain. Specifically, `Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)`, `could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory`, `could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory`, and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1`. See below:

```
$sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
$sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$sudo chroot /mnt
$apt update
........
$apt upgrade
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bubblewrap
The following packages have been kept back:
  libhmsbeagle1v5 phyml
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2-bin bolt desktop-file-utils firefox-locale-en ghostscript
  ghostscript-x gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 git git-man
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-initial-setup grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin
  grub2-common gstreamer1.0-packagekit libapache2-mod-perl2
  libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgs9 libgs9-common libgvc6-plugins-gtk
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
  libpackagekit-glib2-18 libsmbclient libssh-4 libtotem0
  libunity-settings-daemon1 libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless packagekit
  packagekit-tools python-samba python3-distupgrade python3-update-manager
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs smbclient totem totem-common
  totem-plugins ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unity-settings-daemon update-manager
  update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
58 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
387 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/83.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (2: No such file or directory)
(Reading database ... 1326337 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic (4.4.0-121.145) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-121-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a backup of your drive as a safe measure. 
Then, you should be able to walk into the currently installed instance with a method called "chroot" (short for change root) which is described here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

once you have chroot-ed into your original install, you should be able to run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade commands from within, fixing the package issues you had initially.

However, chances are, the installer broke because you had IO issues with your laptop disk (if it's HDD I've seen this happening multiple times) so might be a good thing to check your disk right after creating a backup.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried chroot-ing but get errors about missing files related to an earlier kernel (4.4.0-121-generic). I fear that it in an earlier attempt to free /boot space and resolve the  kernel panic I may have inadvisably manually deleted those... If you have any suggestion that would be great. Otherwise, I think I will take my loss and try a clean install.

Comment: I believe the best shot is to chroot to it again, uninstall old kernels from boot and install any kernel to it. And later resize /boot so it doesn't get broken because lack of space next time

Comment: After chroot, uninstalling old kernels from boot using `sudo apt autoremove` gives the same error listed in my post: `depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory`. Is there a different workaround?  thanks

Comment: this should be created with your kernel install. you can try to do:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic` which should reinstall the kernel completely.  make sure it's followed by `sudo update-grub`  also make sure you actually have space on /boot before doing this. (`df -h` should tell you that in a readable format)

Comment: There is space `/dev/sda6       893G  654G  194G  78%`. Trying `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic` gives me the same errors  as in my last update, e.g. `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-121-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`

Comment: and if you additionally reinstall `linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package` like the installer suggested? what output do you get?

Comment: `$sudo apt-get install reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic` gives me similar errors, e.g. `depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-121-generic: No such file or directory` and `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-121-generic cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic package`